# Ultra-wide monitor support - Screen resolution, Video and Audio Raspberry Pi 4 B

Tags: audio, video, screen, config.txt

**Ultra-wide monitor specs:**
34 inch WHFD (2560 x 1080) IPS Display (21:9) - HD 10 AMD Free sync

**OS:**
Arch linux with Openbox (lightdm)

**Issues:**

1. Managed to get 2560x1080 pixels with `hdmi_enable_4kp60=1` in /boot/config.txt but the default DPI is less meaning that text and icons are too small.
2. When playing video in full screen mode with aspect ratio beyond 720p , it's not smooth as if its skipping frames but still plays, but plays smoothly when played at 720p or below.
3. No audio over HDMI, not sure what I am missing in config.txt

Required information given below, please ask any addition info needed.
Thank you in advance :)

```
[xxx@archlinux ~]$ xdpyinfo | grep -B2 resolution
```

1. screen #0:
2. dimensions:    2560x1080 pixels (677x286 millimeters)
3. resolution:    96x96 dots per inch

`/boot/config.txt` :

1. `gpu_mem=512`
2. `initramfs initramfs-linux.img followkernel`
3. `kernel=kernel8.img`
4. `arm_64bit=1`
5. `device_tree=broadcom/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb`
6. `enable_gic=1`
7. `dtparam=audio=on`
8. `hdmi_drive=2`
9. `hdmi_enable_4kp60=1`
10. `disable_overscan=1`

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted this? It apparently works for the 3B+. These settings go in /boot/config.txt

```
# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
hdmi_timings=2560 0 48 32 80 1080 0 7 20 12 0 0 0 52 0 159838855 7
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_drive=2
framebuffer_width=2560
max_framebuffer_width=2560
framebuffer_height=1080
hdmi_pixel_freq_limit=160000000
```

Source: [https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/aywsn2/configuration_settings_for_ultrawide_2560x1080/](http://Source)